# ColdFusion Flex Application Name

Tags: sql, apache-flex, coldfusion, connection-string

I have Flex app which uses a ColdFusion middle layer with a SQL back end. Our SQL administrator has been asked to log my apps usage on the Database but when he runs profiler the App Name is blank.

I have tried adding Application Name=appName; to the advanced settings of my CF datasource but this did not work.

The SQL back end is 2008 and our CF version is 9. Where do I need to specify the name for this to appear in SQL??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.   Wat value, exactly, in SQL Server is blank?  I didn't believe SQL Server had a concept of apps.  Is ColdFusion sending an app name to sQL Server as part of a query?  Or through some other means?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, so I'll write it as a comment first. In your Application.cfc, write `this.name = "My application";`. Is this what you need, or is it specific to SQL?

Comment: @RIAstar That echos my thoughts.  I can't think of any reason why that CF Application name would show up in a SQL Profiler, though.

Comment: Me neither - I can't see CF providing that information to the SQL server...  now unless other applications are using the same database, why can't the SQL admin just run his reports on the database[s] in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are running a SQL Profiler Log and we wanted something global across all databases on the instance to identify users using the Application. Application Name is one of the fields in the Custom Profile Trace we have created to audit logins.
Got this to work by finding the JDBC URL in the Server Settings on my CF instance and then checking the syntax for Application Name in JDBC. The syntax for which is applicationName=appName; not Application Name=appName as in .net
I then added this to the JDBC URL and put the whole string in to the Connection String box under advanced settings on my datasource on CF Admin.
I will eventually Blog the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the application name to the connection string in cf admin. This will work if you are only running one application or create a dedicated database source for each application.

Comment: I have managed to fix this but the website wont let me answer my own question for another 5 hours grrrr.